# How do I calculate the sum of products of $e$ distinct numbers among $d$ numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $d$ real numbers $x_1,\dotsc,x_d$.
I want to efficiently calculate $y_1,\dotsc,y_d$ defined as follows.
$$y_e=\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_e\le d}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_e}.$$
For example, $y_2$ can be calculated efficiently as follows.
$$
y_1=x_1+\cdots+x_d,\\
y_2=\big((x_1+\cdots+x_d)^2-(x_1^2+\cdots+x_d^2)\big)/2. 
$$
Is there any efficient way to calculate $y_3,\dotsc,y_d$?

Comment: My guess would be no, because (if I am not mistaken), what you are referring to is one of the coefficients in the polynomial $$\prod_{i=1}^d (x - x_i).$$  Assuming that I am right, I have never heard of a shortcut to computing the polynomial by simply multiplying out all of the factors.  I am (naturally) outlawing the use of any computer software to aid in the computations.